# As an HR manager, should I check the resume of my candidates for any misrepresentations or even blatant lies?

Tags: interviewing, resume, job-search, career-development, human-resources

I am just wondering how big the checking of a resume is when it comes to structuring a vetting process for a job position.

Comment: This is a question for your supervisor, not for SE. Anecdotally the contents of resumes are almost not fact checked at all.

Comment: It's entirely situation dependent. If someone with a title in astrophysics from MIT applied for a McJob and proves he's good at flipping burgers, would you fact-check his title?

Comment: If re-phrased to something like: 'Under which circumstances should I as an HR manager fact-check resumes?', would it not be on-topic?

Comment: Instead of ad hoc veracity-keeping, what I am trying to do here is devising a default system of vetting. So I am aware that it depends on the situations. But I am more curious to know what other HR managers do in general.

Comment: @user65173, most companies hire a background check company and then specifies the check done. A minimum check generally checks theemployment history and degree.

Answer (score 2):

While 'cultural elements' company- or country-wise to some degree determine the degree of fact-checking, the specifics of the role are probably more important.

If the position sought is difficult and time-consuming to fill and candidates are known to occasionally 'get creative', at least basic fact-checking seems to be a good investment early on in the process.

If, however, the job is more mundane, candidates plentiful and local employment laws employer-friendly as regards to replacing employees, it would seem rational to only fact-check if a problem arises.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it depends largely on the company/role.  In my experience, the hiring manager looks at the resume and judges whether it appears to hang together or not.  The candidate is expected to demonstrate their skill-set and knowledge during the interview process and defend any holes in their resume.

Having said that, there's no reason why the HR department can't make sure that the resume comes from a reputable source and whether the university/college listed actually exists (or whether it's a known "internet college" where people can buy fake degrees).

Most of this is common sense.